# get rid of error before results show up with php

Tags: php

the below script throws an error before the results the script executed. Though i get the results i want but i want to get rid of the error that throws up.

When the results equals to 1 the error doesn't show up, but when its more than 1  the error comes.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   `C:\xampp\htdocs\server_scripts\complains_list.php on line 1`

```
if(count($customers->User_Name)=='1') {

echo json_encode(array($data));
    }else
    {
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: if(isset($customers->User_Name) && count($customers->User_Name)=='1') {}

Comment: if you're lazy just add `error_reporting(0);` at the top of your script

Comment: The code You showed is the `complains_list.php` file?

Comment: @user7234862, your script worked. Put it in an answer and let me tick it

Comment: If you are smart just ignore the comment of user @hungrykoala and fix the problem. It will pay off later.

Comment: @axiac I agree with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check that variable is set or not, check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset($customers->User_Name) && count($customers->User_Name)=='1') 
{
   echo json_encode(array($data));
}
else
{
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that at some point your `$customer` isn't instantiated. Thus you have to test for its existence :

```
if($customer != null && count($customers->User_Name)=='1') {
    echo json_encode(array($data));
} else {
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```